# FileWriter cycling through Arraylist but not writing to text file

Tags: java, arraylist, filewriter

I'm creating a log in form in Java and I've added a remember me method to store the log in data in a local text file for future us.

The premise is that once the checkbox is checked, the email and password gets written out to the text file.

Here's the code below:

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public void rememberMe() throws IOException {

private final ArrayList<String> storage = new ArrayList<String>();
protected String storPass;
protected String storEmail;


    storage.add(storEmail);
    storage.add(storPass);
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("local.txt"); 
    for(String i : storage) {
          writer.write(i);
          System.out.println("We have written " + i);
        }
      writer.close();
    }
```

with the output being:

```
We have written EMAILADDRESS
We have written PASSWORD
```

The data has been removed, but the printing in the foreach look is showing me that it's cycling through the Arraylist correctly.

The `local.txt` doesn't have any data in it, it's empty before running and empty during and after the program is ran.

Can anybody spot the problem I'm having?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're not specifying what folder the output file is in. Are you sure it is where you expect?

Comment: Does adding "writer.flush();" after each write operation, correct the problem ?

Comment: Actually, your code appears to be nonsense. You have imports followed by the start of a method (not in a class), followed by some private and protected fields declarations (inside a method). Can you post code that makes sense please?

Comment: @khelwood can I use ./src/local.txt instead of just local.txt? It won't have the same directory path all the time so the local file is kept in the src folder

Comment: Just to check it is working, run it into a fully qualified absolute location. Then you will know whether or not the file location is your problem.

Comment: You'd better use an absolute path, preferably one that relates with user preferences (i.e. AppData in the user home).

Comment: @khelwood the absolute path works, guess it was the path that was the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of Using relative path use absolute path like `D:\\local.txt`. It will work

Comment: Yup, used src/local.txt instead of just local.txt and it worked. Marking as complete.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

Path locates/creates the file on the system
Then use the Files object to statically write the file using your list.

```
Path file = Paths.get("local.txt");
Files.write(file, storage, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

This way you can stay away from writing explicit foreach loop.

here is more on the Files object which is available since java 1.7+
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html

Comment: A good answer should have explanation why the provided code works